# Import Contacts from Google in PHP

Tags: php, api, google-api

Using Google Contact API, I imported the contacts from Google to my database table.

```
$client->addScope('profile');
    $client->addScope('email');

    $client->addScope('https://www.google.com/m8/feeds');
    $client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile');
    $client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts');
    $client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.other.readonly');
    $client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/directory.readonly');
    $client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email');

    $client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.labels');

    $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
$contactUrl = 'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?max-results='.$max_results.'&alt=json&v=3.0&oauth_token='.$_SESSION['access_token']['access_token'];
$labels = file_get_contents($surl);
```

Previously my code was working fine; Suddenly, it was not working. I can't access the data through Google API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript code for Google API Contacts - people.people.get.  https://developers.google.com/explorer-help/code-samples#javascript

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>
<script>

  function authenticate() {
    return gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance()
        .signIn({scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly https://www.googleapis.com/auth/directory.readonly https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.addresses.read https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.birthday.read https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.emails.read https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.gender.read https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.organization.read https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.phonenumbers.read https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile"})
        .then(function() { console.log("Sign-in successful"); },
              function(err) { console.error("Error signing in", err); });
  }
  function loadClient() {
    gapi.client.setApiKey("YOUR API KEY");
    return gapi.client.load("https://people.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v1")
        .then(function() { console.log("GAPI client loaded for API"); },
              function(err) { console.error("Error loading GAPI client for API", err); });
  }
  // Make sure the client is loaded and sign-in is complete before calling this method.
  function execute() {
    return gapi.client.people.people.get({
      "resourceName": "people/me",
      "personFields": "names,emailAddresses"
    })
        .then(function(response) {
                // Handle the results here (response.result has the parsed body).
                console.log("Response", response);
                
                
                
              },
              function(err) { console.error("Execute error", err); });
  }
  gapi.load("client:auth2", function() {
    gapi.auth2.init({client_id: "YOUR CLIENT ID"});
  });
</script>
<button onclick="authenticate().then(loadClient)">authorize and load</button>
<button onclick="execute()">execute</button>

 <pre id="content" style="white-space: pre-wrap;"></pre>
```